# What construction can I use instead of Contains?

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a list with ids:

```
var myList = new List<int>();
```

I want to select all objects from db with ids from myList:

```
var objList= myContext.MyObjects.Where(t => myList.Contains(t.Id)).ToList();
```

But when `myList.Count > 8000` i get an error:

> The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not
>   produce a query plan.   This is a rare event and only expected for
>   extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large
>   number of tables or partitions.   Please simplify the query. If you
>   believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer
>   Support Services for more information.

I think that it's because i used `Contains()`. What can I use instead of Contains?

Comment: can you try avoiding the `ToList` and the end and yielding the results when required ?

Comment: What are you using? Linq to SQL? Wich kind of db? Why don't you consider using a stored proc?

Comment: @Vignesh.N - The result would still require the query plan to be built, so I do not believe that would change the outcome.

Comment: @Vignesh.N yeah i not really need in ToList().

Comment: @Sayse - The nested `.Any` will not work with an IQueryable.

Comment: As an alternative, you can upload all data to your client (via myContext.MyObjects.ToList()) and then filter them via LINQ2Objects (using your Where statement). Ofc, this can lack performance if your data is very huge

Comment: There is an [open bug on connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/521943/the-query-processor-ran-out-of-internal-resources-and-could-not-produce-a-query-plan-with-where-in-and-several-thousand-values) regarding this matter.

Comment: You could split your list in several sublists with a smaller number of elements and run separate queries.

Comment: @TravisJ - Yeah, even if it did I don't think it would have been a solution (also the any would have been on the myList not the db)

Comment: @PaoloTedesco - That is a pretty good idea overall, but how to determine the subset size for optimal querying? If you are breaking into smaller numbers, what about lazy loading the entire thing in a loop? I would worry about performance at that point.

Comment: @PaoloTedesco - nice idea will try it.

Comment: Where does myList come from? If it came from DB somehow you should be able to join it instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could split the list in several sub-lists, and run separate queries:

```
int start = 0;
int count = 0;
const int chunk_size = 1000;
do {
    count = Math.Min(chunk_size, myList.Count - start);
    var tmpList = myList.GetRange(start, count);
    // run query with tmpList
    var objList= myContext.MyObjects.Where(t => tmpList.Contains(t.Id)).ToList();
    // do something with results...
    start += count;
} while (start < myList.Count);
```

Of course, you need to find out the good "chunk size" in some way that works for you. Depending on the size of the table and of the list, it might be more convenient to load the entire table and filter in the code, as suggested in other answers.

Comment: Just some other thoughts on this approach. The list of ints could be sorted before the chunking, and the where clause could also include the range of the ids. Perhaps that would provide a little bit of optimization?

Comment: alternatively `var objList = myList.Select((i, x) => new { I = i, X = x}).GroupBy(o => o.X / 1000).SelectMany(g => myContext.Where(t => g.Select(o => o.I).Contains(t.Id)).ToList();` to do it in a single statement.

Answer (score 14):

You can perform the query on the client side by adding `AsEnumerable()` to "hide" the `Where` clause from Entity Framework:

```
var objList = myContext
  .MyObjects
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Where(t => myList.Contains(t.Id))
  .ToList();
```

To improve performance you can replace the list with a `HashSet`:

```
var myHashSet = new HashSet<int>(myList);
```

and then modify the predicate in `Where` accordingly:

```
  .Where(t => myHashSet.Contains(t.Id))
```

This is the "easy" solution in terms of time to implement. However, because the query is running client side you may get poor performance because all `MyObjects` rows are pulled to the client side before they are filtered.

The reason you get the error is because Entity Framework converts you query into something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE column IN (ID1, ID2, ... , ID8000)
```

So bascially all 8000 ID's from the list is included in the generated SQL which exceeds the limit of what SQL Server can handle.

What Entity Framework "looks for" to generate this SQL is `ICollection<T>` which is implemented by both `List<T>` and `HashSet<T>` so if you try to keep the query on the server side you get no improved performance by using `HashSet<T>`. However, on the client side the story is different where `Contains` is `O(1)` for `HashSet<T>` and `O(N)` for `List<T>`.

Comment: @KliverMax: Did you add the `AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: Sorry forgot about `AsEnumerable()`. Whit it your is solution working.

Comment: A lot of times this is actually the most performant way of doing it.

Comment: @Magnus: Yes, except if `MyObjects` returns millions of rows. Then you have to use a more complex server side query.

Comment: @MartinLiversage Yes it depends on the size of the rows. But if only retrieving one column with int for example even millions of rows might not be a problem.

Comment: Lets say the table contains 8 million rows, not unreasonable. Assume that one of the desired "ids" is the last to be returned by the database. 99.99% of the data returned will be discarded. I also assert that the time taken to transfer the selected, and then discarded data across the network, will massively outweigh any other performance savings. Even if your are selecting just the ids, that is 31MB of wasted transfer to get 32Kb of data.

Answer (score 8):

If you wan't this to perform well I'd suggest you use table valued parameters and a stored procedure.

in your database, using TSQL,

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IdSet] AS TABLE
(
    [Id] INT
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get<table>]
    @ids [dbo].[IdSet] READONLY
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
                <Column List>
        FROM
                [dbo].[<table>] [T]
        WHERE
                [T].[Id] IN (SELECT [Id] FROM @ids);
RETURN 0;
GO
```

Then, in C#

```
var ids = new DataTable()
ids.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));

foreach (var id in myList)
{
    ids.Rows.Add(id);
}

var objList = myContext.SqlQuery<<entity>>(
    "[dbo].[Get<table>] @ids",
    new SqlParameter("@ids", SqDbType.Structured)
        { 
            Value = ids,
            TypeName = "[dbo].[IdSet]"
        }));
```

Answer (score 5):

You could create a temporary database table which represents `myList` and refactor your query to a `JOIN` with that temporary List.

The reason for the error is that the actual query produced contains all elements of `myList`.

Basically the DB (the query processor) needs to *see* both lists to do the filtering. If the second list is too large to fit inside the query you have to provide it otherwise (for example as a temp table)

Comment: This sounds excessive and hardcoded. What if the ids were dynamic and the set were different each time?

Comment: Yes thats the point: OP has to create this temp table for **every** query

Comment: That doesn't seem to be much of a workable solution.

Comment: You can add a query-id column to the table so you can use the table for every query. In my opinion the only real workable solution when you have large numbers of id's.

Comment: @Maarten - And how long does it take to store the 8000 ints in the temporary table so they can be used in a single query?

Comment: @TravisJ how long does it normally take to add 8000 tiny rows to a table? Not very.

Comment: @immibis - Depends on the activity on the table. If there is a lot of concurrency, and adding 8000 "tiny" rows and then saving them, you could be looking at a few seconds. Perhaps even over 10 seconds. And that is just to setup the query. Users shouldn't be made to wait for no reason, ideally no longer than 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try

```
var objList= from obj in myContext.MyObjects
     join myId in myList on obj.Id equals myId
     select obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list of IDs come from db, then, instead of using List< int > keep it IQueryable< int > because this will not form sql query with IN clause having thousands of arguments. The IN clause will now have subquery. I am surprised to see nobody has mentioned it yet.

```
IQueryable< int > myList = myContext.Obj1.Where(...).Select(x => x.Id);
var objList = myContext.MyObjects.Where(t => myList.Contains(t.Id)).ToList();
```

If not this, then, I'll suggest to create an extension method to process this in chunks. You can define your own chunk size.

Something like this:

```
 public static class QueryableExtensions
    {
        public static List<T1> WhereContains<T1, T2>(this IQueryable<T1> set, List<T2> values, string property)
        {
            int chunkSize = 5000;
            int currentChunk = 1;
            List<T1> results = new List<T1>();
            int valuesLeft = values.Count;
            while (valuesLeft > 0)
            {
                List<T2> currentValues = values.Skip((currentChunk - 1) * chunkSize).Take(chunkSize).ToList();
                results.AddRange(set.Where($"@0.Contains(outerIt.{property})", new object[] { currentValues }).ToList());
                valuesLeft -= chunkSize;
                currentChunk++;
            }

            return results;
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!